# How to identify the elements(Buttons, text fields) using UIAutomaterview for appium?

Tags: android-emulator, appium, ui-automation

I have opened UIautomatorview in windows 7 64 bit. I tried to identify the element(Sign in) button which is already opened in emulator devices. I can able to take snapshot of that page, but when I tried to inspect the sign in button, It doesn't show anything left panel of UIautomatorview tool. It shows only the frame level thing not able to inspect the specific element. Can somebody guide me how can I do it? else Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate XPath using class and text attribute.
Lets say Class name is `android.widget.Button`
and Text attribute with Value is = `4`
Than the Xpath will be as follows:

```
xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='4']")
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The problem is here I'm not able to inspect any element in chrome browser. It shows only address  bar. When I tried to inspect a button and text box, nothing displayed in left panel. An apparently not able to inspect them.